# ?: Operator Vs. If Statement Performance

Tags: c#, .net, performance, if-statement, operators

I've been trying to optimize my code to make it a little more concise and readable and was hoping I wasn't causing poorer performance from doing it.  I think my changes might have slowed down my application, but it might just be in my head.  Is there any performance difference between:

```
Command.Parameters["@EMAIL"].Value = email ?? String.Empty;
```

and

```
Command.Parameters["@EMAIL"].Value = (email == null) ? String.Empty: email;
```

and

```
if (email == null)
{
    Command.Parameters["@EMAIL"].Value = String.Empty
}
else
{
    Command.Parameters["@EMAIL"].Value = email
}
```

My preference for readability would be the null coalescing operator, I just didn't want it to affect performance.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

IMHO, optimize for readability and understanding - any run-time performance gains will likely be minimal compared to the time it takes you in the real-world when you come back to this code in a couple months and try to understand what the heck you were doing in the first place.

Comment: Of course, bear in mind that a lot of programmers can read ? :  statements just as fast as regular if statements.  In some cases they are even more clear than using if / else statements without braces.

Comment: I agree.  Many posts here are performance questions, asking about minor tweaks (is ++ faster than +=1?) that don't really matter.  Speed comes from algorithmic complexity: reducing massive mem-copies, searching containers quickly, hashing appropriately.  Minor tweaks have no performance impact.

Comment: -1: While chublogga's points are all true and valid and well phrased, they don't answer the original question. The OP is a grown-up who can make his own architecture/readability choices, and casperOne's answer is really a more interesting and direct answer to the specific question of performance.

Comment: I didn't answer the original question because it was the wrong question to begin with.

Comment: Isn't it safe to assume that if a human can see the obvious, a compiler would be smart enough to see that and beyond?

Comment: I personally read coalescing much faster and easier, but that's just me.
Same would be true for ternary operators too

Answer (score 72):

You are trying to [micro-optimize](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html) here, and that's generally a big no-no.  Unless you have performance analytics which are showing you that this is an issue, it's not even worth changing.

For general use, the correct answer is whatever is easier to maintain.

For the hell of it though, the IL for the null coalescing operator is:

```
L_0001: ldsfld string ConsoleApplication2.Program::myString
L_0006: dup 
L_0007: brtrue.s L_000f
L_0009: pop 
L_000a: ldsfld string [mscorlib]System.String::Empty
L_000f: stloc.0
```

And the IL for the switch is:

```
L_0001: ldsfld string ConsoleApplication2.Program::myString
L_0006: brfalse.s L_000f
L_0008: ldsfld string ConsoleApplication2.Program::myString
L_000d: br.s L_0014
L_000f: ldsfld string [mscorlib]System.String::Empty
L_0014: stloc.0
```

For the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx), if the value is `null`, then six of the statements are executed, whereas with the [`switch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), four operations are performed.

In the case of a not `null` value, the null coalescing operator performs four operations versus five operations.

Of course, this assumes that all IL operations take the same amount of time, which is not the case.

Anyways, hopefully you can see how optimizing on this micro scale can start to diminish returns pretty quickly.

That being said, in the end, for most cases whatever is the easiest to read and maintain in this case is the right answer.

If you find you are doing this on a scale where it proves to be inefficient (and those cases are few and far between), then you should measure to see which has a better performance and then make that specific optimization.

Comment: 'L_0006: dup' - Showing my own ignorance here, but why would it need to dup here?

Comment: Ohhh, I see.  If it's non-null it's stored at 000f and not popped.  Makes sense.

Comment: what about string.IsNullOrEmpty()?

Comment: @SkippyFire: That's going to take even more IL instructions, since the method call has to be made, and it will just do something similar to above.

Comment: The method call would probally be inlined when its jitted wouldn't it?

Comment: @JoshBerke: It depends; I don't believe that the conditions of where code are inlined are absolute (although I do believe there are some hard conditions, like virtual methods can't or are not inlined) so I can't say.

Comment: The IL code is not the final, native code, that will eventually get executed by your CPU.

Comment: @JohanBoule Agreed, but it's the closest you're going to get before the JIT takes over.

Answer (score 18):

> I think my changes might have slowed
>   down my application, but it might just
>   be in my head.

Unless you are actually *measuring* performance, it's all in your head and idle speculation.

(Not to pick on you in particular, but it is so disappointing to see question after question about performance micro-optimizations (as well as many of the answers) that do not contain the word "measure".)

Answer (score 7):

I suspect there won't be any performance difference.

Next to that, I wonder why you would have any concerns of favoring one statement over the other in this case ?  I mean:  the performance impact (if there should be any), would be minimal.   IMHO, this would be a kind of micro-optimization, and it shouldn't be worth the effort.
I would choose the statement that is most readable, most clear, and not worry about performance since it would be of minimal influence (in this case).

Comment: The way it was originally written was a bunch of if statements and when I changed it, it seemed like the program took a little performance hit.  Maybe it was an isolated incident but it sparked my interest more than anything.

Answer (score 7):

Almost no significant performance difference in this case.

When the performance difference is negligible, it is all about **readable code**.

Comment: I'd refine that to say "In cases where there is no significant performance difference, it is all about readable code."  Sometimes, there is a performance difference, and sometimes that difference is significant, in which case, code readability may take a back seat.

Comment: How is that any different from what I said?

Comment: @chris-ballance The difference is obviously in where one puts the emphasis.

Answer (score 2):

For discussion sake... if/then/else runs just as fast as the ?: ternary operation as fast as a single level switch/case statement.

[Here are some performance benchmarks with the C# code.](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/what-is-the-fastest-conditional-statement)

It's only when you start getting 2-3 levels deep in case statements that performance starts to be severely impacted. That is, something like this ridiculous example:

```
switch (x % 3)
    {
        case 0:
            switch (y % 3)
            {
                case 0: total += 3;
                    break;
                case 1: total += 2;
                    break;
                case 2: total += 1;
                    break;
                default: total += 0;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            switch (y % 3)
            {
                case 0: total += 3;
                    break;
                case 1: total += 2;
                    break;
                case 2: total += 1;
                    break;
                default: total += 0;
                    break;
            }
            break;
    case 2:
            switch (y % 3)
            {
                case 0: total += 3;
                    break;
                case 1: total += 2;
                    break;
                case 2: total += 1;
                    break;
                default: total += 0;
                    break;
            }
            break;
    default:
        switch (y % 3)
        {
            case 0: total += 3;
                break;
            case 1: total += 2;
                break;
            case 2: total += 1;
                break;
            default: total += 0;
                break;
        }
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a Question of whether machine level code is efficient or Human Readable Code.
As we making it more Readable to us, it makes machine to do Complex interpret the code and vice versa...