# Which one is the best to use, "Conditional Operator (?:)" or "if...else" in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

There are a lot of statements where we can use any one of, conditional operator or `if`..`else`.

So in those statements, which one is the best from a performance point of view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [?: Operator Vs. If Statement Performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547249/operator-vs-if-statement-performance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check 
[Full if/else statement vs. Conditional Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622244/full-if-else-statement-vs-conditional-operator)

[?: Operator Vs. If Statement Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547249/operator-vs-if-statement-performance)

Answer (score 12):

Don't worry about performance. Use which ever is more clear to read.

Comment: @Jeevan: I don't mean to ignore overall performance, I just don't think that *this* will be a bottle neck.

Comment: @Jeevan Bhatt, They will compile to the same msil code, so performance is the same. And even if there was a difference it would be so small that it wouldn't matter for any program that you would write in c#.

Comment: @Jeevan: Seriously, you're worried about completely the wrong thing.  I have an starving 8-way in my laptop ... these questions no longer have any meaning.

Comment: @Mattias: They don't necessarily compile to the same code. It looks like `return sourceValue < 0 ? GetDefaultPositiveValue() : sourceValue;` gives the same IL as `if (sourceValue >= 0) return sourceValue; return GetDefaultPositiveValue();` .

Comment: @jeevan -- you only worry about performance when and only when you encounter a performance problem!

Answer (score 1):

Never ever think about performance. Premature optimizations are the spawn of satan and the root of all evil in hell and earth.

The only time you should worry about performance is if your users/customers complain about it. And then only fix the feature that they complain about.

The thing with developing is to make the code as readable as possible. Doing that makes it a whole lot easier to fix bugs and performance issues compared with code that you've tried to optimizie for perfomance.

As for perfomance, it's usually not regular code such as `if` clauses that hurt performance. It's the network, database operations, alghoritms, parsing strings etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use "?" for assigning a default value to an empty null or otherwise unusable variable.

Use if  .. else .. for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

"Programs are meant to be read by humans and only incidentally for computers to execute"
 - Donald Knuth

So, always if...else. Unless you find a place where ? helps understanding your code.