# ?? null-coalescing operator vs if == null

Tags: c#, if-statement, null, null-coalescing-operator

When instantiating null objects with `??` null-coalescing operator is there any performance difference, additional cycles, etc. vs simple `if == null` statement? Any effect from assigning object to itself?

```
RedColorBrush = RedColorBrush ?? new SolidColorBrush(renderTarget, Color.Red);
```

vs

```
if (RedColorBrush == null)
{
    RedColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(renderTarget, Color.Red);
}
```

Comment: What did you find in compiling and examining the IL produced?

Comment: If there is any difference at all (which is doubtful) it should be so insignificant that your overriding concern should be readability / maintainability, not a possible micro-optimization. (and one that could even be reversed or disappear with the next version of the compiler or VM)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547249/operator-vs-if-statement-performance

Comment: I believe one of the reasons is similar to ternary operator: easier readability for some.

Comment: I opened `.exe` in ildasm, and unfortunately couldn't understand anything), but I actually agree with @abelenky.

Comment: If you want to know if one thing is faster than another, **run it both ways** and then you'll know which is faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385503/which-works-faster-null-coalesce-ternary-or-if-statement) the `??` and `?:` operators might actual be faster (though not by much) because these operators actually evaluate as a value, where as, an `if` statement directs a different line of path, and might result in creating another variable that could have been avoided.

Also, the `??` operator is almost like a specialized case of the `?:`

Edit: It also just looks cleaner and is quicker to type. I for one hate having to retype the same things again and again, which is why I like C#, because it gives a lot of options for shorthand.